# Codeigniter creating dynamic sidebars

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, sidebar

I was looking for a flexible way to generate different sidebars in different pages. The goal is to pass custom links to each sidebar. The template libraries seemed overkill for my application so I developed an easy solution. I'm not certain if it's the best solution. My question is what do you think? Your advice is immensely appreciated!

**1**. In your controller add a private function that loads your sidebar view:

```
/**
 * The function has 2 arguments. 
 * $title is the sidebar widget title.
 * $widget will contain an array of links to be added in the sidebar widget.
 */

private function sidebar($title, $widget)   
{
    $widget['title'] = $title;
    $this->load->view('includes/sidebar', $widget); 
}
```

**2.** In the controller functions that you want to load a custom sidebar, call the private function `sidebar()` and pass desired sidebar data into it.

Below is a controller function named `edit` used to edit posts. In the example I need to load a sidebar with options to view and delete the post I'm on:

```
function edit($post_id = '')
{
    //your code, form validation, etc...

    //Prepare sidebar widget links
    //Array key is link url, array value is link name
    $widget['links'] = array (
        'posts/single/' . $post_id => 'View post',
        'posts/remove/' . $post_id => 'Remove post'
    );
    $this->sidebar('Options', $widget);  //load sidebar  
}
```

**3.** Finally the sidebar view displaying custom data passed from the controller:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li class="widget">
            <div class="label"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($links as $link => $value): ?>
                    <li><?php echo anchor($link, $value); ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Conclusion**

Add the following code to any controller function for custom sidebar title and links:

```
$widget['links'] = array (
            'controller/function' => 'Link Name 1',
            'controller/function' => 'Link Name 2',
            'controller/function' => 'Link Name 3'
);
$this->sidebar('Widget Title', $widget);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that gets it done. I'm not an expert in CodeIgniter, but I can tell you that's just fine. One thing you should always make sure is to validate the data passed to a function. In this case:

```
private function sidebar($title=FALSE, $widget=FALSE) {
   if ($title && $widget) {
      //process
   }
   else
      return FALSE
   }
}
```

Another way to do it is just to pass the links to the template (not the sidebar template, but your main template:

```
$data['sidebar'] = array('link/link'=>'My Link');
$this->load->view('mytemplate', $data);
```

And in the template you load the sidebar template and pass it the data:

```
<html>
<!--All my html-->
<?php $this->load->view('includes/sidebar', $data['sidebar']); ?>
</html>
```

This is just another option. But what you did is just fine.

Comment: thanks that's a good alternative. I usually set the function arguments to an empty string `function sidebar($title = '', $widget = ''`. I haven't tried using `FALSE` before. The private function is good for flexibility. If for instance you want to change the view url you would change it in the private function and not have to edit every function.